# progress dialog displays after task is finished in asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, telnet

Hi i want to display `progressdialog` until a command is executed through `telnet`.
so i use `asynctask` for that purpose.

```
private class AsyncAction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try
          {

              telnet.connect("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", 23);

                // Get input and output stream references
                in = telnet.getInputStream();
                out = new PrintStream(telnet.getOutputStream());

                // Log the user on
                readUntil("login:");
                write("jk");
                readUntil("password:");
                write("kk");

                // Advance to a prompt
                readUntil(prompt + "");
                write("ping -t localhost\n");
                readUntil(">");
                write("cdkk");


                AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(TelSampActivity.this);
                String msg="work finished!";
                alertbox.setMessage(msg);
                alertbox.show();

        } 
          catch (Exception e) 
          {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        finally
        {
            pd.dismiss();
        }





//          pd.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(TelSampActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("loading...");
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }

}
```

And i call `asynctask` in `oncreate()` like below

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try{   

         new AsyncAction().execute();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

The problem is that i could not see `progressdialog` until command executes.
please help me solve the issue.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The code to send and read command

```
public String readUntil(String pattern) {
    try {
    char lastChar = pattern.charAt(pattern.length()-1);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    boolean found = false;
    char ch = (char) in.read();
    while (true) {
    System.out.print(ch);
    sb.append(ch);
if (ch == lastChar) 
{
if (sb.toString().endsWith(pattern)) 
{
    if (sb.toString().contains("cdkk"))
    {
        disconnect();
        break;


    }
    else
    {
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
else
{
    disconnect();
    break;
}
}
else if(sb.toString().contains("Failed"))
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(TelSampActivity.this);
        String error="Invalid username or password!";
        alertbox.setMessage(error);
        alertbox.setTitle("Error");
        alertbox.show();
    System.out.println("bad user name");
    disconnect();
    break;
}

ch = (char) in.read();
}
}
catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}

public void write(String value) {
try {
out.println(value);
out.flush();
System.out.println(value);
}
catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public String sendCommand(String command) {
try {
write(command);
return readUntil(prompt + " ");
}
catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}

public void disconnect() {
try {
telnet.disconnect();
}
catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are trying to do  Network operations from onPostExecute because this method called from UI Thread . change your code as to get work in proper way

```
private class AsyncAction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
     public static boolean status=false;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
          {

              telnet.connect("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", 23);

                // Get input and output stream references
                in = telnet.getInputStream();
                out = new PrintStream(telnet.getOutputStream());

                // Log the user on
                readUntil("login:");
                write("jk");
                readUntil("password:");
                write("kk");

                // Advance to a prompt
                readUntil(prompt + "");
                write("ping -t localhost\n");
                readUntil(">");
                write("cdkk");
               // make status true or false if command successfully executed 
              status=true;

        } 
          catch (Exception e) 
          {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {

       pd.dismiss();
         // check status if true then show AlertDialog
      if(status==true){
       AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = 
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(TelSampActivity.this);
       String msg="work finished!";
       alertbox.setMessage(msg);
       alertbox.show();
     }
    else{
           // your code here
       }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(TelSampActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("loading...");
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: It will show the dialog even if connection is not made.But i need to show this if command is executed perfectly only

Comment: @krishna : how u known command is executed perfectly or not ?

Comment: i am printing the output of command using system.out.println().i could read the exact output of the command that should be displayed.

Comment: i try to say if con is failed then also the dialog on onpostexecute() displays.

Comment: @krishna : where u are using system.out.println() because im not able to see it in current code and use an boolean variable make it true if command executed perfectly and then make it  true before showing dialog

Comment: i have added the code to write the command and read o/p.please have a look at it.

Comment: i will try and let you know.But even then there is a problem.if connection is failed the also it should display error message in catch block.how can i achieve that?

Comment: @krishna : if connection is failed then make status=false; in catch block and in onpostexecute check if status equals to false then show error message

Comment: Thank you  ρяσѕρєя K.You saved my day.your idea of setting status worked fine.now i am able to do all thing needed.+1 for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the progress bar in onPreExecute() do the work in doInBackground() and then hide the progress bar in onPostExecute(). onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() are both executed on the main thread, where as doInBackground is executed in the background.

Comment: I need to show dialog box after finishing the command or if connection fails i need to show dialogbox.Upto my knowledge we cannot use dialogbox in doInBackground.so i need to do it in onpostexecute();

Answer (score 0):

You are doing your work on **onPostExecute()** method which should be inside **doInBackground()**
show your progress dialog inside **onPreExecute()** and dismiss inside **onPostExecute()**.